# Can I run windows commands from a c# form?

Tags: c#, windows

Is it possible for me to call Windows commands, like in the command prompt, from windows forms with C sharp? If so, how?

Comment: What commands do you mean? Something like ping, copy, calc, notepad etc?

Comment: @JamesBlond Any command in general

Comment: Ok, then just have a look at the duplicate link from Ken White. The chosen answer contains everything you need.

Comment: Have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands

Comment: Try Process.Start(). If you are providing a string path to a file, then the file will be opened by the default application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to do the following as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)..

```
Process.Start("Executable name here", "parameters here");
```

However, if you want to set a working directory, capture standard output or errors, create no window etc. You could do something like the following..

```
void StartNewProcess(string processName, string parameters, string startDir)
{
    var proc = new Process();
    var args = new ProcessStartInfo 
    { 
        FileName = processName,
        Arguments = parameters,
        WorkingDirectory = startDir,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true
    };

    proc = Process.Start(args);
    proc.ErrorDataReceived += p_DataReceived;
    proc.OutputDataReceived += p_DataReceived;
    proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
    proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

And then you can process the output using something like this..

```
void p_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Data != null && e.Data.Length > 0) Console.WriteLine(e.Data); 
}
```

Example to call..

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Input params: Executable name, parameters, start directory
    StartNewProcess("cmd.exe", "/C dir", "C:\\");
}
```